# How to detect when device goes to multi-window mode of Android N

Tags: android, service, overlay, android-7.0-nougat, multi-window

I want to get notified from my background service when the user switches to multi-window mode. Is there a way to get this information by a service other than the activities involved in the process.

Also I have noticed that when an overlay is clicked on the area of the foreground window it automatically switches to the activity under the area. Can this be prevented?

Answer (score 4):

You must add ViewTreeObserver. And check if device enter in Multi-Window mode
getActivity().isInMultiWindowMode()

Answer (score 1):

**isInMultiWindowMode()** is added in API 24 to check device is in Multi window or not, it returns a boolean value. when ever device goes to Multi window it triggers `onConfigurationChanged()` method. There you can handle Landscape and portrait mode.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
      {
        //do something
      }else{

      }
}
```

Comment: Is there a similar API to `isInMultiWindowMode`, that can be called outside of an Activity ?

Comment: In case of fragment you can access by getActivity().isInMultiWindowMode() else access by passing context to non activity class

Comment: A fragment is inside an Activity. When it's not attached to Activity, it can't use it... I asked about outside of an Activity...